# FileOutputStream not written to disk on server? Where does the file go?

Tags: java, tomcat, io, fileoutputstream, dynamic-reports

I've been trying to generate report files with Dynamic Reports, however it just doesn't seem to create files on Server. When I use the same method running locally it generates the file, however when I run it on server, there are not files created. I'm running Tomcat 7 in Eclipse. The file is supposed to be created using *FileOutputStream*.

Well here's the method that works locally, but not on Tomcat:

```
StyleBuilder plainStyle = stl.style().setFontName("FreeUniversal");
StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).bold();
StyleBuilder italicStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).italic();
StyleBuilder boldItalicStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).boldItalic();

try {
    report().title(
        Templates.createTitleComponent("Fonts"),
        cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - plain").setStyle(plainStyle),
        cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - bold").setStyle(boldStyle),
        cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - italic").setStyle(italicStyle),
        cmp.text("FreeUniversal font - bolditalic").setStyle(boldItalicStyle))
        .toDocx(createFile("docx"))
//      .show()
        ;
} catch (DRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Oh and the CreateFile(...) method:

```
private FileOutputStream createFile(String extension) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileOutputStream file;
    String filePath = reportsPath + "generated_report." + extension;
    filePath = "generated_report." + extension;
    System.out.println("FILENAME IS: " + filePath);

    file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));

    return file;
}
```

I know the reportsPath here is not active.

So there are no exceptions. By the way, it might be possible that other files don't get created on this server too, because I'm also uploading a file via servlet and it get used, however it doesn't appear anywhere in the path and it doesn't seem to be saved, but I don't need to keep the uploaded files anyway, so it wasn't much of a concern, but now this? I need to be able to find those reports, so the files must get created.

And I'm sure it's not that I can't find the files, I've run the search everywhere, actually in all of my computer on which the server is running, there were no files created with that name...

So, any ideas? It must be a Tomcat configuration issue or something?

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Add the output to your question `filePath`. If no `IOException` is thrown then the file is created. Maybe you should pass in a path, because it could be created inside Tomcat work or tmp directory since you aren't giving it one. Also keep in mind that your `reportPath` must end in `/` unless you use the 2 argument `File(pathName,fileName)` constructor.

Comment: It could even be in your eclipse directory or project directory (whatever the CWD -- current working directory -- is that eclipse executes Tomcat from).

Comment: Thanks. You were right, despite running the searches on disks, I somehow missed, it, now I did find it and I found a way to change Tomcat working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The output was written to the file you supplied in the constructor. If that was a relative filename, it is relative to the current working directory when you executed the code.

Or else an IOException was thrown and the code didn't execute at all.